# execCommand('copy') silently fails in IE when the user answers the prompt with 'Don't allow'

Tags: internet-explorer, copy, execcommand

If the security level is set to at least 'Medium' in IE (tested in Edge & 11) when you execute a execCommand('copy') command, the browser prompts you, asking if you wan to allow the page to manipulate your clipboard.

My problem is, that if you click on 'Don't allow', the execCommand('copy') still returns **true**. Also, no errors are thrown.

How can I catch and handle this user response?

Comment: This is a really weird bug - the thing is, if you refresh the page, it does return false when you disallow again.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but I'll chime in since I just came across this issue myself.

What I ended up doing was to use the fact that IE does support the `document.execCommand('paste')` method. That said, you can paste that copied material into a hidden input and check it against the content that should've been copied.

If a user had allowed the Clipboard to be manipulated, the pasted content and copied content will be the same. Otherwise, they won't be. Something like this:

```
var copySuccess,
    canPaste;

inputElementToCopy.select();
copySuccess = document.execCommand('copy');

inputElementToPaste.select();
canPaste = document.execCommand('paste');

if (canPaste) {
    copySuccess = inputElementToPaste.value === inputElementToCopy.value;

    // Since IE supports paste,
    // if user allowed clipboard: copySuccess === true
    // else: copySuccess === false
}
```